# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 9, size is 1

Tags: android, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

I am working in android `Pull to refresh` listview.Its working fine ,but while refreshing listview ,I am trying to scroll down the list.i am getting this errors:

here is my code:

```
public void Callpagedetails() {

        try
            {


         URL = http://history_thread.php?token_id=" + Token + "&p=" +                       page_count;                   
                Log.d("TAG", "API URL IS " + URL);

                HttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet mGetMethod = new HttpGet(URL);

                HttpResponse mReponseMessage = mHttpClient.execute(mGetMethod);

                String Response = EntityUtils.toString(mReponseMessage.getEntity());

                Log.d("TAG", "O/P Response is " + Response);

                JSONArray responseObject = new JSONArray(Response);

                          for(int i=0; i < responseObject.length(); i++)

                    {
                        obj = responseObject.getJSONObject(i);

                        listhashmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                        listhashmap.put("text",obj.getString("text"));

                here i am storing the item in arraylist arraylistitems


                    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}

    }
```

Where the arraylistitems is   `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arraylistitems;`

where `Callpagedetails()` is the method from where i am getting the data

```
    01-20 18:22:17.755: E/InputEventReceiver(23393): Exception dispatching input event.
01-20 18:22:17.755: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 9, size is 1
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3816)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at com.listview.HistoryListView.onTouchEvent(HistoryListView.java:316)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at com.listview.HistoryListView.onInterceptTouchEvent(HistoryListView.java:380)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2113)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1466)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2436)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2061)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7425)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3376)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3308)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4402)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4380)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4484)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
01-20 18:22:17.775: E/MessageQueue-JNI(23393):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 9, size is 1
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3816)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at com.listview.HistoryListView.onTouchEvent(HistoryListView.java:316)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at com.listview.HistoryListView.onInterceptTouchEvent(HistoryListView.java:380)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1886)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2113)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1466)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2436)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2061)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7425)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3376)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3308)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4402)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4380)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4484)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
01-20 18:22:17.785: E/AndroidRuntime(23393):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could somebody help me out. Thanks.

Comment: How can we help without code?????

Comment: Please post refresh methods code

Comment: check whether you change adapter when you scroll down.

Comment: when did you call RefreshTask.execute()?

Comment: You should for sure add all the code of your adapter extension, there's the key of why it fails.

Comment: I meant you should update your initial question and add that part of the code so someone may have a look at it and see what's working wrong.

Comment: listhashmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

Where is the declaration of that variable? Do you use it somewhere else? Could you post the source of Questionadapter?

Comment: I don't see the declaration, only the definition as I quoted in my previous comment. Do you access listhashmap anywhere else than callpagedetails()? Could you post the source of Questionadapter?

Comment: @sai how am i supposed to do that can you provide the exact way...@thanks

Comment: @sai I agree with your comments, but I don't think there are concerns about `ArrayList` class line 304, because it is under `java.util` package. Probably the problem is here : `at com.listview.HistoryListView.onTouchEvent(HistoryListView.java:316)` or `at com.listview.HistoryListView.onInterceptTouchEvent(HistoryListView.java:380)`

Comment: @priya maybe you should check whether the received JSON data and the data in `ArrayList` is equal.

Comment: @topher i have checked it is same

Comment: @sai may be it is related to pure coding..can you figure it out why i am getting this error

Comment: @priya try to catch the error across the ArrayList

Comment: @sai i have added that too...my issue is while i try to refresh it working fine,if i will not touch BUT while pull to refresh ,if i touch the listview i am getting this error

Comment: Ok, then my small suggestion is to REFRESH DATA in "onBackground()" and DON'T change the data in the Listview immediately While the "PULL-TO-REFRESH" is called. Then onPostExecute(), update your ListView. (I think may be you are just setting to SCROLL the ListView when it is either NULL or starting to populate(Less then ArrayList.size() leading to outOfBounds)). So, you can touch your ListView until it is updated. :-)

Comment: @sai yeh i am refreshing data in Background,and updating in postexecute..

Comment: Not exactly Priya, i think you are calling this, "Callpagedetails()" in your "doInBackground()" which in turn calls change to your ListView while in "Background" only.

Comment: Just get the data in 'doInBackground()' and set it to listView in 'onPostExecute()' [Just guess;-(]

Comment: @sai how could i change it to listview in background,can you provide some detailed answer thanks

Comment: @priya, I suggest you to check code below.

Answer (score 3):

i am not trying but sure it may be help you.

```
                JSONArray responseObject = new JSONArray(Response);
                listhashmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                for(int i=0; i < responseObject.length(); i++)
                {
                    obj = responseObject.getJSONObject(i);
                    listhashmap.put("text",obj.getString("text"));

                }
```

Comment: Yes get last item because you use static "text" value.. in Hashmap should be different key assign. it same keypass than only one record(Last) show. So pass key value different.  like listhashmap.put(obj.getString("uniqueKey"),obj.getString("text"));

in uniqueKey pass your id field. and you can fetch record by this id

Comment: also pass listhashmap.put(i,obj.getString("text")); you can resolve your proble

Comment: i have tried like this but i am getting last item only

Comment: Please, Make sure your key value is different. Please check log before insert in listhashmap.put(key,value).

Comment: i am using  listhashmap.put(string,string).

Comment: insted of string put i as a key, because if your string value is same than it consider only one item in hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

You should not touch an adapter's data in a non-UI thread.

Your `doInBackground()` seems to set a count that's possibly used by an adapter to zero and also guessing that `Callpagedetails()` directly modifies the data used by the adapter.

Instead, modify the adapter's data in the UI thread. `onPostExecute()` is a good place for that.

Comment: thanks but i am modifying the adapter's data in onPostExecute() only

Comment: The code you posted doesn't modify the underlying data in `onPostExecute()`, it just essentially calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`. So I'm guessing you're modifying the data in `doInBackground()` then.

Comment: But in Callpagedetails() i am retreiving the data and store in array only

Comment: ... and I'm assuming that very same array is concurrently used by the adapter.

Comment: is there anything that i could change

Comment: Collect data into another array and swap it into the adapter in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

On your Callpagedetails, take a look at your for loop after instanced responseObject.

You keep initial listhashmap. It is why you listhashmap size is 1. Replace the new HashMap to outside for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < responseObject.length(); i++) {
    obj = r esponseObject.getJSONObject(i);
    listhashmap = new HashMap < String, Object > ();  // problems code
    listhashmap.put("text", obj.getString("text"));
}
```

Comment: you mean i have to call the listhashmap outside of the for loop

Comment: ya, instance your listhashmap outside the loop.

Comment: then only first item getting stored in listview

Answer (score 0):

protected class RefreshTask extends AsyncTask>> {

```
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            page_count = 0;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data=Callpagedetails();
            return data;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result!=null)
        {
             adapterfirst = new Questionadapter(historylist.this,result);
             listviewfirst = (RefeshListView) findViewById(R.id.listquestion);
             listviewfirst.setAdapter(adapterfirst);
                adapterfirst.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
         yourlistView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                 new RefreshTask().execute();  
            }
        }, 1000);

}
        }
    }
```

Hi Priya ! try this procedure! It is always a good way to pass the objects to onpostExecute as a parameter! Hope this will fix your issue!

Comment: i have tried that but while refreshing if try to scroll the listview i am getting the error

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exact . but try to modify accordingly,

```
 public void Callpagedetails() {

    try
        {
     URL = http://history_thread.php?token_id=" + Token + "&p=" +                       page_count;                   
            Log.d("TAG", "API URL IS " + URL);

            HttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet mGetMethod = new HttpGet(URL);

            HttpResponse mReponseMessage = mHttpClient.execute(mGetMethod);

            String Response = EntityUtils.toString(mReponseMessage.getEntity());

            Log.d("TAG", "O/P Response is " + Response);

            JSONArray responseObject = new JSONArray(Response);

                      for(int i=0; i < responseObject.length(); i++)

                {
                    obj = responseObject.getJSONObject(i);


                }
  }
catch(Exception e)
{
 System.out.println(e);
}

}
```

and , in your

```
doInBackground() {
   ....
 CallPageDetails();

}
```

and,

```
 onPostExecute() {
                    if(yourListView!=null) {
                  listhashmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                    listhashmap.put("text",obj.getString("text"));

            here YOU WILL BE storing the item in arraylist arraylistitems
  &&  also set, 
            yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
        .....
        .....


}
```

*-> Try at your Own Risk.

Comment: why try at your own risk

Comment: same issue...and only single array is receiving

Comment: Ok, that's why not exact, but try to do search on "EndlessAdapters" and "ListView + ScrollView"'s , Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

arraylist hold object refrence so your list hold only last value becuase you are new object on same memory locaion.

```
for (int i = 0; i < responseObject.length(); i++) {
    obj = r esponseObject.getJSONObject(i);
    listhashmap = new HashMap < String, Object > ();  // problems code
    listhashmap.put("text", obj.getString("text"));
}
```

replace with

```
for (int i = 0; i < responseObject.length(); i++) {
    obj = r esponseObject.getJSONObject(i);
 **HashMap<String, Object> listhashmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();**

                        listhashmap.put("text",obj.getString("text"));

                here i am storing the item in arraylist arraylistitems
                         rraylistitem.put(listhashmap);
}
```